# How to specify win32 or Windows 64 target with cross compiler i686-w64-mingw32-gcc

Tags: gcc, cross-compiling, fedora

I have recently downloaded the mingw-w64 package under Fedora Linux in order to be able to cross compile targetting both win32 and "Windows 64". But I fail to understand how to specify what target I want to use. What flags do I need to supply to gcc and to the linker in order to choose my target architecture?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

W32 and W64 are two different architectures, so you distinguish by compiler name. The debian mingw-w64 calls them i686-w64-mingw32-gcc for Win32 and x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc for Win64.

Comment: Thanks. I had missed the fact that there are alternate packages for x86_64 named mingw64-* under Fedora that provide the x86_64-w64- versions of the compile chain.

Comment: Why does i686 contain w64, if i686 is a 32-bit architecture?