# How can I tell whether my GCC is compiling 64bit by default?

Tags: gcc, 32bit-64bit

is there any way to know whether GCC is compiling 32 or 64bit code by default?

my GCC version is 4.1.2. my os kernel version is x86_64.

thanks.

Comment: perhaps write, compile & run a tiny program like: `std::cout << sizeof( long ) * 8`

Comment: A related question regarding the specifics on the windows platform: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7441552/how-to-specify-win32-or-windows-64-target-with-cross-compiler-i686-w64-mingw32-g

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Type `gcc -v`.  Amongst other things, it will tell you the target platform.  For instance, I get:

```
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
```

Answer (score 2):

As @Oli said, the configuration should tell you, but it's possible to screw with that after the fact.

For belt and braces, simply compile something, and then use `file` to examine the output file.